# Why is the else statement in my Javascript setInterval function not working?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, setinterval

```
<button id="friends" class="btn btn-primary large3">Friends</button>

setInterval(changeFriendBtnSize, 1000);

  function changeFriendBtnSize() {
    let upDown = 'up';
    if (document.getElementById('friends').getElementsByClassName('large3')) {
      console.log('111');
      document.getElementById('friends').classList.remove('large3');
      document.getElementById('friends').classList.add('large4');
    } else if (document.getElementById('friends').getElementsByClassName('large4')) {
      console.log('222');
      document.getElementById('friends').classList.remove('large4');
      document.getElementById('friends').classList.add('large3');
    }
  }
```

in my console log, it logs 111 over and over again every second but never logs 222. the class large3 gets removed and large4 gets added but never the other way around, why?

Comment: When does `document.getElementById('friends').getElementsByClassName('large3')` return something falsy ? Look up `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @torazaburo getElementById is fast enough, it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
document.getElementById('friends').getElementsByClassName('large3')
```

always returns a node list. The list may be empty, but it will still be an object reference and will never test as `false`.

As far as I can tell, `.getElementsByClassName()` is not the API you're looking for anyway. Your code apparently wants to check which class the button currently has; to do that, you'd want to check the `classList` with `.contains()`:

```
if (document.getElementById('friends').classList.contains('large3'))
```

or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById('friends').getElementsByClassName('large3')` finds elements with class "large3" inside the element with id "friends" (and always returns a node list), e.g.:

```
<div id="friends"><div class="large3"></div></div>
```

You are looking for a check if the classList contains `large3`:

```
if (document.getElementById('friends').classList.contains("large3"))
```

and

```
else if (document.getElementById('friends').classList.contains("large4"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this greatly with `classList.toggle()`.

```
<button id="friends" class="btn btn-primary large3">Friends</button>

setInterval(changeFriendBtnSize, 1000);

function changeFriendBtnSize() {
  var elt = document.getElementById('friends');

  elt.classList.toggle('large3');
  elt.classList.toggle('large4');
}
```

For some reason, a lot of people have learned `classList.add` and `classList.remove`, but not `classList.toggle`, which turns out to be very useful, especially with its second argument which lets you write

```
elt.classList.toggle('cls', bool);
```

instead of having to write

```
if (bool) elt.classList.add('cls');
else elt.classList.remove('cls');
```

Answer (score 1):

In your condition you are looking for children inside friends, which is what `.getElementsByClassName` does. Instead you need to check if the friends element contains a classname:

Like so:

`document.getElementById('friends').classList.contains('large3')`